# Programming with 32bits 64bits machine compatible in linux

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I wish my source code to be compatible between 32 bits and 64 bit machine in terms of source level not object level in linux.

Q1) Then, what should I have to take care of? One thing that I think is,  I need to take care of integer to pointer casting.
If I use "long int", it will be 32bits length at 32bits machine and 64bits length at 64 bits machine? What is the appropriate way?
I'm thinking if I can use "long int".

Q2) Is there anything that my application was complied for 32 bits or 64 bits?
For example, using a build argument?

Comment: Q2 see -m32 -m64 gcc options

Answer (score 0):

1. The proper way to have "an integer the same size as a pointer" is to use a `size_t` (same size as `unsigned long int`) and `ssize_t` (same size as `long int`).
2. If you write `gcc file.c`, it will compile 32-bit on 32-bit machines, and 64-bit on 64-bit machines. If you run `gcc -m32 file.c`, it will compile for 32-bit regardless of your machine, and similarly `gcc -m64 file.c` will compile for 64-bit regardless of machine.

You don't need to do anything special to write portable C code; you rarely need to think about architecture while writing C code. For example, this runs just fine whether you compile with `gcc -m32 hello.c` or `gcc -m64 hello.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main() {
   printf("hello, world\n");
}
```